# Save items in IIS application cache

Tags: caching

In my C# web application I need to save some items in the application cache and then retrieve those items by key. To save those items I'm using the following code:

```
HttpContext.Current.Items["urlname"] = "something";
```

That saves the item fine in the Items hashtable. However I'm not able to get the value of "urlname" in another location in the application.

Could anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong or maybe there's a better way of doing this?

Thanks.

**[EDIT]** Ok, now I know that the Items hashtable is a storage with very short lifetime. The contents will be deleted once the response is sent to the browser. So, how can I save my data in other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpContext.Current.Items is a per request store.

You should use HttpContext.Current.Session if you want to store and access values across multiple pages.

Have a read of this - https://web.archive.org/web/20201202215202/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/060904-1.aspx

Other thing to consider is something like memcached - CouchBase have a Windows implementation